# Scala Play Framework Manipulating a Redirect(Result) or ResponseHeader

Tags: java, scala, cookies, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am trying to get the cookies from a `Redirect` which is a `Result` type in the Play Framework.

In one of my methods, I returned a `Redirect` with cookies. However in my other methods receiving the redirect, there doesn't seem to be an option to `getCookie` by name or something of that sort.

I think I would actually need to manipulate the `ResponseHeader` but I am not sure. Anyone have ideas on this?

Here is what I am trying

```
val x = responseReturn() // this method returns a Result
x.header.headers("Set-Cookie")

def responseReturn(): Result = {
   val redirect = Redirect(s"$redirectURL").withCookies(cookies: _*)
   redirect
}
```

from x I can't see to access the cookies and individual get or select them

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see exactly what you are trying?

Comment: yes I have added my code